# Filter a dataframe by first call date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am trying to filter a dataframe by the first call date in a way to remove the other rows that comes after that first call.

```
    client_id       date        duration_in_sec incoming_number     avg
    4               13/01/2016  94              0632108564          55.5
    4               15/01/2016  17              0632108564          55.5
    5               13/01/2016  339             0699309366          339.0
```

I am trying to keep only the rows for clients to know when they've made their first call, so the dataframe above, will keep only the row for client id where date is `13/01/2016` since it's his first call date.

I've tried to do a groupby minimum date but couldn't reach a good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
df.loc[df.groupby('client_id')['date'].idxmin(), :]
```

**Output**

```
   client_id    date    duration_in_sec incoming_number avg
0   4   2016-01-13  94  632108564   55.5
2   5   2016-01-13  339 699309366   339.0
```

This is given that your `date` column as casted as `datetime`-

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```